# Using Prototype, is it possible "redirect_to" avoiding to process the full "js.rjs" code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, prototype, format, respond-to

In *user_controller.rb* file I have this code:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if test = true
        format.js
    else
        format.js { @yo = true }
    end
end
```

In *update.js.rjs* file I have this code

```
page.redirect_to :action => "index" if @yo == true
page.replace_html...
...
```

This is a hack to redirect a Java responce passing a variable (@yo == true). However I think is better to do something like "redirect_to" in braces **avoiding** to process the code in *update.js.rjs*:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if test = true
        format.js
    else
        format.js { redirect_to ... } # something example
    end
end
```

but I do not know how to do that or whether it is possible. Can anyone advise me on the issue?

Comment: Well, if you're going to redirect, why not just do it directly with format.html? Why are you using js to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different .js files in your respond_to block.

```
respond_to do |format|
    if test = true
        true.js
    else
        false.js
    end
end
```